# Зацикленное нажатие по кнопке

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Есть одна кнопка в вконтакте, как сделать её зацикленное нажатие с неким интервалом через Console в Ctrl+Shift+C? Раньше находил такой для добавления и мгновенное удаление из друзей в "Одноклассниках":

```
setInterval (()=>{ 
document.querySelector('#hook_Block_MainMenu > div > ul > li.u-menu_li.view_lvl1.__hl > a').click(); 
setTimeout(()=>{ 
document.querySelector('#hook_Block_MainMenu > div > ul > li.u-menu_li.view_lvl1 > div > div > ul > li > a').click(); 

},1140); 
}, 
2200 
)
```

Сама кнопка: https://vk.com/dev/messages.removeChatUser
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вариант использовать автокликеры не годиться? Если сойдет, то используйте Clickermann с его возможностью записи и редактирования сценариев.